# Manipular objetos de array jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Tenho uma li que recebe vários valores, elas possuem a mesma class. Preciso pegar esses valores e passar para campos hidden pra enviar via $_POST para uma página PHP. Eu consegui trazer os dados que necessito, porém preciso agora passar esses dados um a um.

```js
$(function() {

  var x = [];

  $('#selecao .active').each(function() {

    x.push($(this).val());

  });

  $('.p').text(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selecao">
  <input type="text" class="active" value="Conteudo 1" />
  <input type="text" class="active" value="Conteudo 2" />
  <input type="text" class="active" value="Conteudo 3" />
  <input type="text" class="active" value="Conteudo 4" />
  <input type="text" class="active" value="Conteudo 5" />
  <input type="text" class="active" value="Conteudo 6" />
  <input type="text" class="active" value="Conteudo 7" />
  <input type="text" class="active" value="Conteudo 8" />
  <input type="text" class="active" value="Conteudo 9" />
  <input type="text" class="active" value="Conteudo 10" />
  <p class="p"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa criar o elemento e adicionar ao `form`:

```
$(function() {
    $('#selecao .active').each(function() {
        $('<input/>', {
            type: 'hidden',
            name: 'selecao[]',
            value: $(this).val()
        }).appendTo('#form');
    });
});
```

Saída:

```
<input type="hidden" name="selecao[]" value="Conteudo 1">
<input type="hidden" name="selecao[]" value="Conteudo 2">
...
```