# Pegar o valor de uma li e criar um input hidden com o valor quando a li for clickada

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-select2

Bom dia senhores, estou tendo dificuldades para realizar uma ação. Quero que quando clicado na li, ela adicione na div #form um input type hidden com o valor da li. e que isso aconteça apenas quando clicar uma vez.

```html
<div id="selecao">
  <input type="text" class="active" value="Conteudo 1" />
  <input type="text" class="active" value="Conteudo 2" />
  <input type="text" class="active" value="Conteudo 3" />
  <input type="text" class="active" value="Conteudo 4" />
  <input type="text" class="active" value="Conteudo 5" />
  <input type="text" class="active" value="Conteudo 6" />
  <input type="text" class="active" value="Conteudo 7" />
  <input type="text" class="active" value="Conteudo 8" />
  <input type="text" class="active" value="Conteudo 9" />
  <input type="text" class="active" value="Conteudo 10" />
  <input type="text" class="active" value="Conteudo 11" />
  <button class="btn" type="button">Show</button>
  <div id="form">

  </div>


</div>
```

O conteúdo da li é dinâmico gerado por php, sendo assim a unica coisa que muda são os valores, eu tentei pegar todos os campos da ul através da função each() mas o problema é que o cliente pode querer selecionar outros elementos e então ele acaba não atualizando direto.

Conto com a ajuda de vocês e desde já eu agradeço!

Comment: Publique o trecho em html das listas para que eu posso lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ideia é a mesma da minha [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78017/4622) na sua outra pergunta. Só é preciso atribuir a função ao evento `click()`:

```
$("#selecao .active").click(function() {
    $('<input/>', {
        type: 'hidden',
        name: 'selecao[]',
        value: $(this).val()
    }).appendTo('#form');
});
```

Comment: Bom dia Lúcio, obrigado por salvar meu trabalho mais uma vez! Na verdade eu tinha testado de algumas formas parecidas com essa que você postou agora e não deram resultado positivo, já na outra questão eu adicionei uma função clique e selecionava todas, essa que você postou agora serviu como uma luva! Abraço!